# whitespace under nav bar (overflow)

Tags: html, css, overflow, whitespace

Trying to remove the whitespace under my navigation bar, when you inspect element and disable overflow: hidden the whitespace disappears?

https://i.gyazo.com/b2f412e61b09f24348a02fd5b7d4bdf3.png > with overflow
https://i.gyazo.com/cbd9766f50c97a732064133a8a77e25a.png > without

Naturally it also removed the background color so I'd like to find another fix for this problem?

```
    body {
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #EEEEE7;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

button {
    color: #FE5B3C;
    background-color: #2B211F;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}

/* The dividers */

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: url('images/studying.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    clear: both;
}

.container h1, p {
    color: #FE5B3C;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .5em;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: no wrap;
    background-color: #2B211F;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-topnav {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 32px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FE5B3C;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #EEEEE7;}

/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

/* When the screen is less than 680 pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

and html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Basic Page Needs -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Your Landing Page!</title>

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- FONT -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Favicon / How to Edit:    Make sure the type="" is the right type. Then change the href="" to the path of the image/.ico file you'd like to use. -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/mortarboard.png">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul class="topnav">
            <li><img src="images/icons/medal.png" class="img-topnav" alt="Home"><a href="#home">Personal Tutors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to Personal Tutors!</h1>
            <button>Find a Tutor!</button>
            <p> This is a test to see if the font is working. </p>
        <div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, your `<div class="container">` is missing the closing `</div>`. You have a `<div>` instead of `</div>` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the overflow property. The whitespace is actually the top margin of the h1 tag.

An easy and quick fix would be to replace the h1 margin top with padding.

Try to add this to you code:

```
.container h1 { 
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Haha damn you're right. I never noticed that! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad i could help :)